# MVP Passive View - Where to wire up the view's events?

Tags: c#, mvp

I used to simply just have an `ApplyPresenter()` method on my view, but technically that is not passive view if the view knows about the presenter and calls methods on it.

So rather than calling `presenter.AButtonClicked()`, I can expose an event from the view, like `event EventHandler AButtonClicked`, which the presenter then subscribes to.

But where do I subscribe to `AButtonClicked`?  If constructors should do no work except field assignments, I can't do it in the constructor.  I could have an `Initialize()` method (or call it `Setup()` maybe) on my presenter, but wouldn't that be a code smell?

Should I just do some additional work in the constructor and subscribe to the view's events there?

Comment: I don't understand; Why not in the `Presenter's Constructor` again?

Comment: I did implement somewhat like this. I injected the view in fact it's interface into the presenter and subscribed all the view's event in the constructor.

Comment: Use `Start` and `Stop` methods on your presenter to tell it when to subscribe to / unsubscribe from events on your view. Give a higher-level component the responsibility of telling the presenter when to start and stop.

Answer (score 0):

> Should I just do some additional work in the constructor and subscribe to the view's events there?

You can do it in constructor - it is an OK place to do event bindings.

**Or** you can introduce an event broker, say IEventBroker, that lets your components publish and subscribe to events.

In presenter:

```
public MyPresenter(
    IEventBroker eventBroker, ...)
{
   this.eventBroker = eventBroker;

   this.eventBroker.Subscribe("UpdateButtonClicked", this.WhenButtonClicked);
}
```

And in view:

```
public MyView(
    IEventBroker eventBroker, ...)
{
   this.eventBroker = eventBroker;
}

private void someButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   this.eventBroker.Fire("UpdateButtonClicked", new EventArgs<Item>(lineID));
}
```

**Or** you can say that people often define *Passive View* as

> View that is not responsible for updating itself from the model

Which says nothing about view's knowledge about controller/presenter. So you can leave your `ApplyPresenter()` method as is.